# Magento 2.2.2 custom observer attribute name not valid atomic type

Tags: module, event-observer

I have a custom observer for admin `admin_system_config_changed_section_{{$section_name}}` the following are:

`events.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
<event name="admin_system_config_changed_section_section_name">
    <observer name="custom_admin_system_config_change_section_name" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\ConfigObserver"/>
</event>
</config>
```

Where `section_name`  in `system.xml`:

`...<section id="section_name ...`  and when loaded in the backend url:

`.../admin/system_config/edit/section/section_name/...`

Observer class:

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface as Logger;

class ConfigObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var Logger
     */
    protected $logger;

    /**
     * @param Logger $logger
     */
    public function __construct(
        Logger $logger
    ) {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
    {

        //$this->logger->info($observer->getWebsite());
        //$this->logger->info($observer->getStore());
    }
}
```

When go load the backend url I get error:

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid XML in file .../htdocs/app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml/events.xml:
Element 'event', attribute 'name': [facet 'pattern'] The value 'admin_system_config_changed_section_section_name' is not accepted by the pattern '[a-zA-Z_]+'.
Line: 3

Element 'event', attribute 'name': 'admin_system_config_changed_section_section_name' is not a valid value of the atomic type 'eventName'.
Line: 3

Element 'event', attribute 'name': Warning: No precomputed value available, the value was either invalid or something strange happend.
Line: 3
```

What seems to be the problem here? as far as I can see it's within naming convention `[a-zA-Z_]+`

Answer (score 0):

It's a Bug.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/12758.

It can't accept numbers.

Thanks